# IntelliJ idea selecting multiple non-continuous items in menus (like ovverride methods...) with keyboard

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to know whether it is possible to select multiple items in menus like those of method overriding, implementing, menu with bookmarks etc with keyboard. It is possible to select it with mouse - Control + click or continuous block with shift + arrow. But I want to select non-continuous items - something like file managers, where you cold do something like space and directory and it got marked then you could select another item.

I tried all space combinations but without success. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without a mouse right now, please [vote for the open issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-12937).